# Por que a pergunta do BIRL foi fechada e tão negativada?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Estávamos discutindo no chat a respeito de uma pergunta feita, relacionada a linguagem zoeira [BIRL](https://github.com/birlscript/birlscript/).

[Existe alguma engine que usa a linguagem B.I.R.L.?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191996/existe-alguma-engine-que-usa-a-linguagem-b-i-r-l#191996)

Eu me lembro de ter feito uma pergunta sobre [Brainfuck](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113985/qual-%C3%A9-o-objetivo-dessa-linguagem-chamada-brainfuck) que não foi tão mal recebida assim. Só pra constar: Assim como BIRL Language, Brainfuck também é considerada uma linguagem esotérica.

Qual foi o problema na pergunta acima e o que pode ser feito pra resolver esse tipo de situação?

Será que o problema foi o formato ou conteúdo? Se sim, será que, como o @Gabe diria, não bastaria apenas uma edição?

Eu sei a resposta pra ela e gostaria inclusive de responder :p

Comment: Acredito que pela forma que foi perguntada e pelo comentário do autor, parecia que ele só queria divulgar que encontrou uma nova linguagem aí pela internet. Acredito que se ela for bem formulada pode se tornar interessante e respondível.

Comment: Acho que o problema maior é na definição de "engine" que ele quer saber... Perguntar se existe algum projeto, ou alguma aplicação "séria" para linguagens exotéricas me parece perfeitamente cabível no site, mas a incerteza sobre o que ele quis dizer por "engine" torna a pergunta mais complicada de responder dentro dos nossos padrões.

Comment: [Meus dois cents](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/birl/info). Ah, a linguagem [tem completude de Turing](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/132402/85476).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Discordo. Veja [esse meu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191996/existe-alguma-engine-que-usa-a-linguagem-b-i-r-l#comment397674_191996).